# how print an array row with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\rati\\Desktop\\iris_flower.txt");
float s=0;
int x,n=5,m=150,i,j;float d[5]={0};
float **iris;
float ss=n;
iris=new float *[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
iris[i]=new float [m];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
fin>> iris[i][j];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
for(j=0;j<m;j++)
cout<<iris[i][j]<<" ";
cout<<endl;        
}
for(j=0;j<m;j++){
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
s+=iris[i][j];
d[j]+=s/ss;
cout<<s<<endl;
}

system ("pause");    
}
```

this is my full code. I want to print a row from 2d array with pointer(no loops).I hope you can write a fragment to add that it did what I want

Comment: Arrays have zero based indexes so it prints out the 6th row not the 5th.

Comment: So use recursion like @Captain Obvlious

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the array with pointers but if you want to print the array, you have to use loops.

Check out this example:-

```
int main() {
int n = 3, m = 4, a[n][m], i, j, (* p)[m] = a;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        a[i][j] = 1;
p++;
(*p)[2] = 9;
return 0;}
```

Here

`p` is a pointer to a 4-element `int` arrays (i.e. a pointer to pointer to `int`, where the first dimension is 4 and the second is unknown). When you increment `p`, it points to the next 4-element `int` array, i.e. the fifth `int` altogether. Then `p` is dereferenced with offset 2, which means that the seventh `int` changes, so you get

```
  1 1 1 1
  1 1 9 1
  1 1 1 1
```

For converting integer array pointed by p to string, try this :-

```
string int_array_to_string(int *p, int size_of_array){
string returnstring = "";
 for (int temp = 0; temp < size_of_array; temp++)
  returnstring += itoa((* p)[temp]);
 return returnstring;
}
```

You get the row array from here.

Comment: I know but the homework is to print a row with a pointer, I surfed on google but no answers :((

Comment: In Java 5 Arrays.toString(arr) or Arrays.deepToString(arr) for arrays within arrays. and add Note that Object[] version calls .toString() of each object in array.
Use import java.util.Arrays;

Answer (score 0):

With array of ints it wont be so easy like array of chars.

```
int n=10, m=10;

int width, height;
char **tab = new char*[n];
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
tab[x] = new char[m];
}
   
 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
 tab[i][j] = rand()%10 + '0';


for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { for(int j=0; j<n; j++) cout << tab[i][j]; cout << endl; }
cout << endl;

cout << tab[5];
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/Z3n7DI)

## /// edit ///

if u cant use loop and recursion u can do this

```
const int n=3;
float *k =new float [n];

k[0]=6.123;
k[1]=9.5345;
k[2]=1.32423;

int i=0;

label:
if(i<n){
    cout << *(k+i) << " ";
    i++;
    goto label;
}
```